# 'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'OrderByDescending'

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

Can someone explain why the statement compiles with `OrderBy` but not with `OrderByDescending`? Seems to me it should work: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534316(v=vs.100).aspx

> 'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for
>   'OrderByDescending' and no extension method 'OrderByDescending'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Target framework is `.Net 4.5.1`.
The type of `entity` is `System.Data.Entity.DbSet`

```
var comparisonQuery = new ComparisonQuery();
comparisonQuery.Query = entity.Where(whereStatement)

.OrderByDescending(GenOrderByFragment()). // no go

Select(GenBigRowResultObject(elements, idFieldName)).AsNoTracking();
```

Comment: Looks like you're using `IQueryable` instead of `IQueryable<T>`

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski There's not an `OrderBy` extension method for `IQueryable` in the framework eoither.

Comment: What type does `GenOrderByFragment()` return?

Comment: Is `entity` the non-generic `DbSet` or `DbSet<T>`?

Comment: @d-stanley `GenOrderByFragment()` returns a string. `entity` is the non-generic version

Comment: The documentation you linked to is for the generic version of IQueryable I believe.  The non-generic version has almost no extensions on it.

Answer (score 1):

@d-stanley your original comment sent me in the right direction.
Turns out that `OrderBy` was implemented through a custom extension, not a framework's extension like I immediately assumed.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As you elaborated in a comment above, GenOrderByFragment returns a string. However, OrderByDescending expects a `Func<Entity, string>`.

For example:

```
// this works
Func<Person, string> keySelectorGood = p => "Name";
var goodQuery = entityContext.People.Where(p => p.Name == "John").OrderByDescending(keySelectorGood);

// this DOES NOT WORK
Func<string> keySelectorBad = () => "Name";
var badQuery = entityContext.People.Where(p => p.Name == "John").OrderByDescending(keySelectorBad);
```

Comment: Your response makes total sense but my problem was even simpler, a bad assumption on my part... Thanks